# Magento - Custom Delivery Price with respect to Place and Amount

Tags: magento-1, magento-1.7, module, checkout, shipping

I am a newbie in Magento. I am using Magento 1.7.

My Client want me to add different Delivery Prices according to the Country, Amount and Weight. 
This is what he wants.

```
1. STANDARD DELIVERY in UK is £7, 
2. FREE DELIVERY in UK orders above £100, 
3. EUROPEAN COUNTRIES is £10 for items below 5kg
4. REST OF THE WORLD IS is £19.99
5. System automatically add £5 per 5kg in UK 
6. £15 per 5kg in rest of the world
```

Is there any modules that help me to add different options like these? 
Or did I want to create a new module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with the table rates and cart rules.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

You set up the table rates based on weight vs destination. And then something like:

```
Country    Region    Zip    weight    Shipping Price
   // 1. STANDARD DELIVERY in UK is £7, 
   UK        *       *       0             7     
   // 5. System automatically add £5 per 5kg in UK 
   UK        *       *       5            12     
   UK        *       *       10           17     
   UK        *       *       15           22     
   UK        *       *       20           27     
   UK        *       *       25           32     
   UK        *       *       30           37
   // add more rows     
   // 3. EUROPEAN COUNTRIES is £10 for items below 5kg
   DEU       *       *       *            10
   FRA       *       *       *            10
   ... // all other european countries
   // 4. REST OF THE WORLD IS is £19.99
   *         *       *       0           19.99
   // 6. £15 per 5kg in rest of the world 
   *         *       *       5           34.99
   *         *       *       10          49.99
   // add more rows
```

Cart rule for:

> 1. FREE DELIVERY in UK orders above £100,

There is one undefined case: What costs EU >= 5kg?

Comment: Thanks for help @FabianBlechschmidt. It is working Good. 
I add [Shopping Table Rate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-table-rates.html) too. 



Is there a way to make (£5 per additional 5kg) automatic via table rates? 

Thanks again.

Comment: No, there is not - afaik.

Answer (score 1):

I answered it already, but it should be achievable with this extension too: https://github.com/thebod/Thebod_Shippingrates and it is with a GUI :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the OwebiaShipping2 extension. This extension is very flexible, it allows creating multiple shipping rules configured exactly as you wish.